# Exception in Crystal Report within VS 2008

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I use VS-2008 with embedded Crystal report. My Desktop Application worked fine in server, but after a month Crystal Reports started giving this error.

> Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore the error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

When I run a report in my application it works fine.

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: The connection of app with sql server 2008 is ok working normally but when i want to print report using crystall report then the above error displayed, though i chked firewall, ip configuration, servername all are ok but still the problem exist in reporting..